# Ping via android

Tags: android, ping

Há algum jeito de mostrar a média de ping no android? Vi alguns tutoriais mas o máximo que consegui foi o seguinte:

```
public void fExecutarPing(View view){
    List<String> listaResponstaPing = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLista = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listaResponstaPing);

    try {
        String cmdPing = "ping -c 4 " + host;
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(cmdPing);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLinhe;

        while((inputLinhe = in.readLine())!= null){
            listaResponstaPing.add(inputLinhe);
            //adiciona para cada linha
            listaPing.setAdapter(adapterLista);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro: "+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

Que mostra o ping, junto com o resto das informações.
E o que eu preciso é que mostre somente a média de ping.
Como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Vamos levar em consideração esta linha do resultado:

> 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms

O que lhe interessa é a seguinte parte:  `4 received`.

Para pegar este número, vamos utilizar o método [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Segue um exemplo:

```
private Integer getPacotesRecebidos(final String fulltext){
    /**
     * Parte inicial do texto que vamos buscar na fullText
     */
    final String textStart = "packets transmitted,";
    /**
     * Pegamos o indice onde começa esta parte do texto mais o seu tamanho
     */
    int start_ = fulltext.indexOf(textStart) + textStart.length();
    /**
     * Pegamos o indice onde começa esta parte
     */
    int end_ = fulltext.indexOf("received,");

    /**
     * Através do substring, pegamos a parte específica da string
     */
    final String s = fulltext.substring(start_, end_);

    /**
     * Transformamos a String em um Integer (trim: remove os espaços em branco)
     */
    return Integer.valueOf(s.trim());

}
```

**Utilização**:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    try{
        String cmdPing = "ping -c 4 www.google.com";
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(cmdPing);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLinhe;
        /**
         * Vamos pegar o resultado!
         */
        final StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputLinhe = in.readLine())!= null){
            buff.append(inputLinhe);
        }

        final Integer pacotesRecebidos = getPacotesRecebidos(buff.toString());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pacotes Recebidos: "+pacotesRecebidos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (final Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: opa, vou testar aqui.

Comment: não funcionou. tentei passar `pacotesrecebidos` pra um textview e mesmo assim nada é exibido

Comment: Como passou? Consegue debugar ou colocar um log para ver?

Comment: `W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=19; regionLength=-20`

Comment: Veja se o texto possui **received**? Pode mostrar o texto completo?